# Admob banner shown but crashes when tap. Crash only on iPhone, works fine on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, admob

I have universal binary app and start using Admob.
Here is a code for viewcontroller.

The banner is shown as expected but when I tap the banner, the app crashes. Strangely, it occurs only on iPhone. No problem for iPad.

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape];

bannerView_.adUnitID = @"myid";

CGRect screen_size = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

bannerView_.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                               screen_size.size.width - bannerView_.bounds.size.height,
                               bannerView_.bounds.size.width,
                               bannerView_.bounds.size.height);

//2nd line, screen_size.size.width - bannerView_.bounds.size.height works good not screen_size.size.height - bannerView_.bounds.size.height

bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

This is a log whenever the app crahes.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2ec82f0b 0x39415ce7 0x2ec82e4d 0x31523bf9 0x315238d1 0x3159b57d 0x3159a5f9 0xefc04 0x3144b361 0x2ec86454 0x2ebd09a7 0x398fed53 0x398fed3f 0x399016c3 0x2ec4d681 0x2ec4bf4d 0x2ebb6769 0x2ebb654b 0x33b136d3 0x31515891 0x1d5a9 0x39913ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I would like to have any ideas or solutions for this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: i believe you may need to return NO to -(BOOL)shouldAutoRotate in your rootViewController or add -(NSUinteger)supportedInterfaceOrientation and return uiinterfaceorientationMaskPortait

Comment: @NicolasManzini Thanks a lot. I googled and found many similar post as  your suggestion. My error occurs on iOS7. Is the solution applicable to iOS7, too?

Comment: Solved. I made UINavgationcontroller+Rotation category and wrote @NicolasManzini 's code. Also, the cause of the crash is... Appstore does not have Landscape view for iPhone, but my app was only Landscape mode by general setting. With the code and put check on portrait on the general setting (plist), works great.